# Как вставить фон (картинку) в элементы:before маркированного списка, адрес на которые прописан в соседнем маркированном списке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два маркированных списка. У одного в атрибутах `data-img` элементов `li` прописаны `url`ы картинок, которые должны стать фоном у элементов `li a:before` второго маркированного списка.
попробовал несколько вариантов:

1. не подставляет фон в before, но если удалить из строчки

   `$("ol.flex-control-nav li a:before").eq(i).css({` `:before` и оставить:

   `$("ol.flex-control-nav li a").eq(i).css({`, то фон нормально применяется к самим тегам `a`

```js
$(".backround").each(function(i) {
  var bg = $(this).attr("data-img");
  $("ol.flex-control-nav li a:before").eq(i).css({
    background: "url(" + bg + ")"
  })
})
```

```css
.backround {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: #ccc;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  /* Убираем маркеры */
}
li.but {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
ol.flex-control-nav {
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  background-size: cover!important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
a:before {
  content: "";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parent-view">
  <li class="backround" data-img="http://goodimg.ru/img/tsvetochek-risunok3.jpg"></li>
  <li class="backround" data-img="http://agu-shop.ru/images/pink_flower_512x512.png"></li>
  <li class="backround" data-img="http://www.raskraska.ru/counting/flower-bw.gif"></li>
</ul>
<ol class="flex-control-nav">
  <li class="but"><a>1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="but"><a>2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="but"><a>3</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

2. еще попробовал к порядковому номеру элементов `li` обратиться но фон все еще в before не вставляется...

   ```js
   $(".backround").each(function(i) {
      var bg = $(this).attr("data-img");
      $("ol.flex-control-nav li:nth-child(" + i + ") a:before").css({
        background: "url(" + bg + ")"
      })
    })
   ```

   ```css
   .backround {
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
     width: 30%;
     height: 50px;
     margin: 2px;
     background: #ccc;
   }
   li {
     list-style-type: none;
     /* Убираем маркеры */
   }
   li.but {
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
     margin: 5px;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     border: 1px solid red;
     text-align: center;
   }
   ol.flex-control-nav {
     text-align: center;
   }
   a {
     background-size: cover!important;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: block;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <ul class="parent-view">
     <li class="backround" data-img="http://goodimg.ru/img/tsvetochek-risunok3.jpg"></li>
     <li class="backround" data-img="http://agu-shop.ru/images/pink_flower_512x512.png"></li>
     <li class="backround" data-img="http://www.raskraska.ru/counting/flower-bw.gif"></li>
   </ul>
   <ol class="flex-control-nav">
     <li class="but"><a>1</a>
     </li>
     <li class="but"><a>2</a>
     </li>
     <li class="but"><a>3</a>
     </li>
   </ol>
   ```

   подскажите как все таки можно его туда прикрепить?

Comment: из яваскрипта **нельзя** обращаться к любым псевдоэлементам

Comment: это мне только стилями задавать остается?

Comment: да, только стилями

Comment: вот попробовал еще вот так:(http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496099/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно вставить нужные правила в css

```js
$(".backround").each(function(i) {
  var bg = $(this).data("img");
  document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("ol.flex-control-nav li:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ") a:before{background-image: url(" + bg + ")}", 0);
})
```

```css
.backround {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: #ccc;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  /* Убираем маркеры */
}
li.but {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
ol.flex-control-nav {
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  background-size: cover!important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
a:before {
  content: "";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parent-view">
  <li class="backround" data-img="http://goodimg.ru/img/tsvetochek-risunok3.jpg"></li>
  <li class="backround" data-img="http://agu-shop.ru/images/pink_flower_512x512.png"></li>
  <li class="backround" data-img="http://www.raskraska.ru/counting/flower-bw.gif"></li>
</ul>
<ol class="flex-control-nav">
  <li class="but"><a>1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="but"><a>2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="but"><a>3</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Что то наподобие как раз пробовал, как раз вашим методом наиболее близок был. А что значит [0] и 0 в конце строки?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов в [0] Первую таблицу стилей ... добавить правило перед 0 первым правилом

Answer (score 1):

В [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#grammar) есть следующие строки:

> **NOTE:** Authors are advised that while the use of pseudo-elements in selectors is permitted, they will not match any elements in the document, and thus would not result in any elements being returned. Therefore, authors are advised to avoid the use of pseudo-elements in selectors that are passed to the methods defined in this specification.

То есть, использование псевдо-элементов селекторах разрешено, но так как они не соответствуют ни одному элементу, то и возвращены они не будут. А так как их нельзя получить в яваскрипте, то и стиль, в яваскрипте, им нельзя присвоить.